# Add column to display the value of each unique column value, repeated for all instances of that value in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In pandas, I would like to add a new column which displays the value for an elements type, repeated for all instances of that element (couldn't figure out a better way to describe this).

For example, in the below, there is a Type called "La". I want to create a new column called "La". In the case of element "A", for each record, the value 9 should show under the LA column. For "B", it would be 2.

My Data:

```
Element     Type  Value
A           Ex     5
A           La     9
A           Bd     0
B           La     2 
B           Ex     7 
B           Ex     3
```

What I want:

```
Element     Type  Value  La
A           Ex     5     9
A           La     9     9
A           Bd     0     9
B           La     2     2
B           Ex     7     2
B           Ex     3     2
```

EDIT: For the value I'm looking at (La), there won't ever be duplicates. Just one per element.

Comment: What should happen if you have duplicates? Like Ex/B?

Comment: Should have mentioned, there won't ever be duplicates of LA. Just one per element.

Comment: So you just want La?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only "La" and assuming there are no duplicates, filter and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['La'] = df['Element'].map(df.loc[df['Type'].eq('La')]
                               .set_index('Element')['Value']
                             )
```

Output:

```
  Element Type  Value  La
0       A   Ex      5   9
1       A   La      9   9
2       A   Bd      0   9
3       B   La      2   2
4       B   Ex      7   2
5       B   Ex      3   2
```

If you want all Elements, use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) (here keeping the max value in case of duplicates, but you can aggregate with any function):

```
df.merge(df.pivot_table(index='Element', columns='Type', values='Value',
                        aggfunc='max', fill_value=-1).reset_index(),
         on='Element', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  Element Type  Value  Bd  Ex  La
0       A   Ex      5   0   5   9
1       A   La      9   0   5   9
2       A   Bd      0   0   5   9
3       B   La      2  -1   7   2
4       B   Ex      7  -1   7   2
5       B   Ex      3  -1   7   2
```

Comment: @TheDataPanda I got overly enthusiastic, I still provided the generic approach as it might be interesting to future readers ;)

Comment: No problem. It'll be good for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
df.assign(La = df['Value'].where(df['Type'].eq('La')).groupby(df['Element']).transform('first'))
```

Output:

```
  Element Type  Value   La
0       A   Ex      5  9.0
1       A   La      9  9.0
2       A   Bd      0  9.0
3       B   La      2  2.0
4       B   Ex      7  2.0
5       B   Ex      3  2.0
```

or if you want them all:

```
(df.join(
    df['Type'].str.get_dummies()
    .where(lambda x: x.ne(0))
    .mul(df['Value'],axis=0)
    .groupby(df['Element']).transform('first')))
```

Output:

```
  Element Type  Value   Bd   Ex   La
0       A   Ex      5  0.0  5.0  9.0
1       A   La      9  0.0  5.0  9.0
2       A   Bd      0  0.0  5.0  9.0
3       B   La      2  NaN  7.0  2.0
4       B   Ex      7  NaN  7.0  2.0
5       B   Ex      3  NaN  7.0  2.0
```